# Remote testing with capybara-mechanize: Form submission results in incorrect URL (404 => Net::HTTPNotFound)

Tags: forms, capybara, http-status-code-404, mechanize

App being tested: CakePHP app running on a Vagrant vm

App doing the testing: local (basically blank) Rails app with [capybara-mechanize](https://github.com/jeroenvandijk/capybara-mechanize)

```
 10 examples, 1 failure
```

The failure is:

```
 404 => Net::HTTPNotFound
```

Let's say my vm has the app running on

```
 'www.domain.comx'
```

The failure scenario goes to the home page, logs in, clicks on create new something, fills out the form for it and clicks save.

The test then looks for the info that should be on the returned page (if saved correctly).

The code runs up to the form submission with no problem, but then the saving URL gets strange.

Instead of going from

```
 'www.domain.comx/something/new'
```

to

```
 'www.domain.comx/something/create'
```

It's going to

```
 'www.domain.comx/something/something/create'
```

and throwing the error.

Somewhere in the code there's a place where it duplicates the 'something' in the URL.

What could be causing this issue?

I've been trying to look into redirects and things, but can't seem to find a solution.

The app is live and has been used by a team of 25(ish) people for almost 5 years. The test should be passing.

Here's the trace, in case that helps:

```
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-mechanize-1.5.0/lib/capybara/mechanize/browser.rb:125:in `rescue in process_remote_request'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-mechanize-1.5.0/lib/capybara/mechanize/browser.rb:103:in `process_remote_request'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-mechanize-1.5.0/lib/capybara/mechanize/browser.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Browser>'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:69:in `process'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:41:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:32:in `submit'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/form.rb:80:in `submit'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-mechanize-1.5.0/lib/capybara/mechanize/node.rb:8:in `click'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:143:in `block in click'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:143:in `click'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:25:in `click_link_or_button'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:810:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
 # /Users/ViviPoit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
```

Here is a dumbed down version of the form's html:

```
 <form id="create" method="post" action="something/create">

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="usuario_email">E-mail *</label>
    <input type="email" name="data[usuario][email]" id="usuario_email" class="form-control">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="usuario_nome">Nome *</label>
   <input type="text" name="data[usuario][nome]" id="usuario_nome" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="usuario_telefone">Telefone *</label>
    <input type="text" name="data[usuario][telefone]" id="usuario_telefone" class="form-control" alt="phone">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <div class="pull-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="salvar">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </button>
   </div>
  </div>

 </form>
```

Comment: What is the HTML of the form?

Comment: I just added the form's html to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be acting correctly since your action path is relative.  For the behavior you expect the forms action attribute would need to be “create” (relative), “/something/create” (absolute), or “../something/create” (relative) depending on whether or not you’re using the same form at different URLs and how it should behave at those too.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Changing the form's action to “/something/create” worked.